# MySQL users specific tables or 1 big table / user-specific table naming

Tags: mysql

I'm starting a project where every users of my web application will store results (times from stopwatch) from their "playing sessions" in my database.  For each playing session, I have to store a row with 9 columns.  Users can complete many playing sessions per day so over time one user can store thousands of rows.  I plan on having thousands of users (50k - 200k)

I already have my "user" table where all the users main infos are stored and where a unique ID is given to each user.

Question is : should I store all the "playing sessions" from all the users in a big table or should I create a table for each user and then store their results in it?

If you suggest me to create a table for each user (so thousands of tables), how should I name these tables?  As of now, I proceeded this way and named my table like this : "id_results".  So the table for a user with id=1932 will be "1932_results".  And then my queries in PHP looks like this:

`"SELECT * FROM " .$id. "_results "` where `$id` has been defined previously with the correct user id.

Is this a good way to proceed? What would you suggest me instead?

EDIT:  Users will have to access their results quite frequently as they can see their personal results in a personal "Statistics" page where their results are shown in a table and graph.  Results are pulled from my DB dynamically (ajax) as the user choose the period "Last week", "Last month", etc.  So, queries have to be handled quickly.

Comment: Don't create a table for each user.  Don't *ever* do that.  Seriously.  Create a table of sessions and use a foreign key to link its records to the user record that owns them.

Comment: One table. But why 9 columns?

Comment: Strawberry - 9 columns because one playing session has to store 6 results + 3 infos relative to the session (datetime, object used, technique used).  I forgot to mention that I need quick access to these results because one player can see his own stats and evolution in his personal "stats" page.  Stats are pulled from my DB dynamically (ajax) as the user choose the period like "last week", "last month", etc in a select form. I will add this in my question.